# php rename() function permission denied even folder permission is 775

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, permissions, command-line-interface

i'm using php rename() function to move file from `/home/vsftpd/` into `home/photo/upload`. each folder is in www-data group and already `chmod` to write by group.
but everytime i run my script, it always say :

```
 PHP Warning:  rename(/home/vsftpd/arie.heptabyte@gmail.com/bebas.jpg,/home/photo/upload/55f1185a129595b9bf8b4570/tmp/111DF153189852CDBC505B223ACED5F0F8B1416264E798E98B01C5112A75CD5C.jpg): Permission denied in /var/www/photoclient/cli/ftp.php on line 71

Warning: rename(/home/vsftpd/arie.heptabyte@gmail.com/bebas.jpg,/home/photo/upload/55f1185a129595b9bf8b4570/tmp/111DF153189852CDBC505B223ACED5F0F8B1416264E798E98B01C5112A75CD5C.jpg): Permission denied in /var/www/photoclient/cli/ftp.php on line 71
```

> And here my code at line 71, other line just assign data into other section

```
   rename ('/home/vsftpd/arie.heptabyte@gmail.com/bebas.jpg', '/home/photo/upload/55f1185a129595b9bf8b4570/tmp/111DF153189852CDBC505B223ACED5F0F8B1416264E798E98B01C5112A75CD5C.jpg');
```

> this is folder permission info

```
drwxrwxr-x  3 photo  www-data 4096 Sep  7 13:51 photo
drwxrwxr-x  4 vsftpd www-data 4096 Sep 14 10:57 vsftpd
```

i wonder, what's wrong here?

> other post that similar with this question just say to change the
>   permission at parent folder. and i've done it.

thanks

Comment: Try by granting `755` or `644` permission to the source and destination

Comment: Please make sure to add the solution by submitting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by granting `755` or `644` permission to the source and destination folders